# Compare 2 strings with their occurrence and group them according to size in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 string arrays str1 and str2 given below. str2 is all the possible combination of str1. The output which I am looking for is, if I give input as 'n' number, total length of possible outcome should be 'n' size with all occurrence of each str2 char element.

```
str1 = [a,a,b,a];
str2 = [aaba, aab, aaa, aa, aba, ab, aa, a, aba, ab, aa,a, ba, b, a];
```

Here total 3 a's and 1 b's in str1. so output should contain full group of individual chars.

Output I  am looking for is

```
i/p is 1 o/p is none
i/p is 2 o/p is none
i/p is 3 o/p is aaa
i/p is 4 o/p is aaba
i/p is 5 o/p is none.
```

My code is

```
$scope.input = [1,2,3,4];
$scope.str1 = [a,a,b,a];
$scope.str2 = [aaba, aab, aaa, aa, aba, ab, aa, a, aba, ab, aa,a, ba, b, a];
$scope.output = [];

for(var i =0; i< $scope.input.length;i++){
  $scope.lengths = $scope.str2.map(function (word) {
       if (word.length == $scope.input[i]) {
             return word;                        
         }
       });
   $scope.output = $scope.output.push($scope.lengths);
}
```

I am getting output as

```
i/p is 1 o/p is a, a, b, c
i/p is 2 o/p is aa, ab, aa, ab, aa, ba
i/p is 3 o/p is aab, aaa, aba, aba
```

Comment: You're comparing length with word where as you need to compare lengths, so this should be `word.length == $scope.input[i].length`

Comment: @CodeManiac if (word.length == $scope.input[i]), I am comparing "word.length" with "$scope.input[i]" where $scope.input[i] is a length of the output

Comment: I have explained in simple manner here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381794/get-the-possible-combination-of-strings-with-n-length-and-conditions-in-angula